# How to log MDC context values in New Relic

Tags: java, spring-boot, newrelic, spring-logback, newrelic-platform

I am using logback to print the log in my spring boot project. I can see the log printing in the new relic, but it does not print the values from the MDC context.

for example:
I have stored `x-request-id` in the MDC.context and am using the following config file to print the log. I can see the `x-request-id` printing in the `Console` and in the log file in the `logs/logback-app.log` location, but I do not see the `x-request-id` printing in NewRelic.

I am taking reference from this https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/logs/logs-context/java-configure-logs-context-all/#java-logback documentation.
An example from: https://github.com/newrelic/java-log-extensions/blob/main/examples/logback-app/src/main/resources/logback.xml

```
<configuration>
    <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender">
        <file>logs/logback-app.log</file>
        <append>false</append>
        <!-- encoders are assigned the type
             ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder by default -->
        <encoder class="com.newrelic.logging.logback.NewRelicEncoder">
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <appender name="ASYNC" class="com.newrelic.logging.logback.NewRelicAsyncAppender">
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
    </appender>
    
    <appender name="Console" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <encoder class="ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder">
            <pattern>%X{request-id} %d %-5level [%thread] %logger{0}: %msg%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <root level="TRACE">
        <appender-ref ref="ASYNC" />
        <appender-ref ref="Console" />
    </root>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

New Relic has provided a flag to forward Diagnostic Context to the new relic agent, we can enable this flag in the newrelic.yml file as follows

```
common: &default_settings
    # forwad Diagnostic Context to new relic agent
    forwarding:
        context_data:
            enabled: true
```

Comment: Is doing this alone enough? I've seen some things that seem to indicate using `<NewRelicLayout/>` is also necessary. It's part of NewRelic's java-log-extensions project (specific to Log4j2, in my case)? https://github.com/newrelic/java-log-extensions/blob/main/log4j2/README.md